# Has combustion of premixed LCH4 and LH2 with LOX been investigated for larger rocket engines?

Tags: methalox

I can only find two papers on blended methane/hydrogen combustion not related to internal combustion engines, and both of those (Mento et al. 2009 and Rosen et al. 2011) are very limited in scope. I don't have access to RPA nor any physical injectors with which to fool around with, so I was wondering if anybody (possibly in the industry) was aware of research being conducted on this subject.

Comment: Another chance to "advertise" the open-source program [cpropep](http://rocketworkbench.sourceforge.net/equil.phtml) (C code is available [here](http://rocketworkbench.sourceforge.net/index.phtml)). It is an (old) open-source implementation of [NASA's Chemical Equilibrium with Applications (CEA)](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/CEAWeb/). Both tools allow to calculate the performance of different fuel combinations.

Comment: premixed LCH4 and LH2 should exist as liquid only without boiling of hydrogen or freezing out methane, but their boiling points are not very close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the temperatures that methane is liquid, hydrogen is a gas.  You can dissolve hydrogen in it, but you can’t mix in bulk amounts.

NASA [studied that](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19680020605.pdf) in detail. They found solubility of parts per thousand, not enough to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that this is feasible for liquid fuels. Liquid hydrogen critical temperature is –400.4°F (–240.2°C). Freezing point of liquid methane is −182.5 °C; −296.4 °F. Therefore liquid hydrogen is to cold for methane and will freeze it. This will eventually cause injector clogging and critical failure of rocket engine. Some radical injector design or tripropellant design should be considered in order to utilize mix of this two but the advantages of this mixture are unknown because what you get on overall density you lose on specific impulse.

Comment: I am aware. Do you have a source that experimentally confirms this? Hydrogen can be gelled with methane so it's not theoretically impossible.